# Should i get state data via component or redux-thunk middleware ? React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

It said to

> Do more in action-creators and less in reducers

So, should i:

1. Pass current state data via component ?

   `this.props.fileActions.addFile( Object.keys(this.props.fileById).length )`
2. Or get state data inside of an action-creator via redux-thunk ?

   `export const addFile(){
    return (dispatch, getState) =>{
     const filelength = Object.keys(getState().fileById).length;
     dispatch(addFileAction(filelength))
    }
   }`

P.S. I come from Angular world, where in most times i store data in Services, call Service.addFile() and the files.length is already stored in service resulting in no need to pass Service.addFile(files.length)

Comment: I think either way would work, and there are other options as well. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Let's say i have an array of file ids [1,2,3], a resource map of files {1:{id:1...}...}. When i'm adding a file, it's name is ``File ${fileCount}``, like a ``File 4``.

I'm used to keep components thin as possible, passing data via component looks unobvious for me. Using redux thunk looks weird as well, cause from and angular point of view i would do this in a reducer, as it has info about it's state, but it's prohibited by styleguides and i can't do any async actions in reducers.

Comment: @ArneHugo

i am trying to transform angular to react|redux            
                          
`export class FileService {
addFile(){
 const length = Object.keys( this.fileById ).length
 const file = {name:'File'+length}
 $http.post('/api/flies', file).then((file)=> this.fileById[file.id] = file)
}
}`

Comment: Ok. Could you move the updates from comments into the question itself? And please include code for both (1) action creator(s), (2) reducer(s) and (3) component(s) for at least one of the cases you are proposing. Also, why is `length` the variable name for file id? Why not `fileId`?

Answer (score 0):

Prefer the latter usage.

Passing params to action creators from components makes your components coupled with data and means you probably can not reuse this component.

Answer (score 0):

For your use-case it seems like you should do that in the reducer

```
function addNewFile() {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_NEW_FILE'
  }
}

function filesReducer(state, action) {
  if(action.type === 'ADD_NEW_FILE') {
    const newId = state.filesById + 1;
    return {
      filesById: state.filesById.concat(newId),
      entities: Object.assign({}, state.entities, {
        [newId]: {name: `File ${newId}`}
      })
    };
  }
  // some other action handlers
  return state;
}
```

You are going to modify state upon some action. This is exactly what reducer supposed to do.